# Why does my Perl script hang when trying to talk to server?

Tags: perl, tcp

**Introduction**

I'm  following the book "Network programming with Perl" by Stein. This is the 2nd Perl script in the book, where the script attempts to communicate using the correct protocols with a daytime server to get the date and time from the server as a response.

**read first-line from remote server**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
# file: lgetr.pl 

use IO::Socket; 


my $server = shift; 
my $fh = IO::Socket::INET->new($server); 
my $line = <$fh>; 
printf $line;
```

**Running Script (already made it executable with chmod)**

The book then uses this server as an argument to connect to.

> wuarchive.wust1.edu:daytime

```
./lgetr.pl wuarchive.wust1.edu:daytime
```

**The problem**

When executed, the program just hangs. I'm guessing the program is waiting for a response from the server. Does this mean that the server doesn't exist any-more? or have typed it incorrectly? How would I get this to work, or would my best bet be creating my own daytime server? (i have a bit of experience of this in C)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try some of the servers mentioned here: http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi (the first hit on Google for "daytime").

Also, don't use [printf](http://p3rl.org/printf) where [print](http://p3rl.org/print) is enough, especially where there's no format strings.

Moreover, it seems you need the second line, not the first one.

You can use a loop to print all the lines instead:

```
print while <$fh>;
```

Works for me with e.g. `time.maconbibb.us:daytime`.